# Does a Modal force a re-render on an entire component?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Does a modal (as seen in this example https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) force a re-render of everything inside the return statement, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After profiling the render, I confirmed that this sort of modal DOES force a re-render of everything inside the return statement.

Because ReactDOM.createPortal is used internally by the modal, it should be attached to whatever component is causing it to render.